# Does gcc "-fvisibility=hidden" hurt when applied to standard c compiled executables

Tags: c, gcc, cflags

I am compiling ngspice. Its configure.ac adds -fvisibility=hidden to all compile steps, not only during generating the 'code models' that are shared libs.

Is there a risk if -fvisibility=hidden is added during compiling of the standard executable?

Comment: Risk of what happening? What do you mean / What is a "standard" executable?

Comment: standard executable = not a shared library

Comment: Risk: Will not compile, will not function correctly if other settings, environments are chosen than the one I have now (openSUSE Leap 42.3)

Answer (score 2):

For standard executables, it is normally not necessary to have any visible symbols, except `main`. However, it seems compilers are smart enough to keep `main` visible if you compile with `-fvisibility=hidden`.

The exception is when your program is made to load plugin libraries at runtime using `dlopen()`, and those plugins expect to be able to call functions in the main program. Your plugins will then not be able to find the required symbols.

Answer (score 1):

No. It'll just slap an attribute on external symbols and that attribute will get ignored by the linker when it sees it's making an executable (unless you're using `-rdynamic`/`-Wl,--export-dynamic`). What might hurt performance, on the other hand, is compiling with `-fpic/-fPIC` as that will slow your code down a bit. `-fpic/-fPIC` is unnecessary for executables unless they're position-independent executables (PIE).

Comment: Modern distros compile with `-fPIE` by default due to security reasons.